# Codeforces - problem: (A) Mike and palindrome

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

While on SO someone posted this question and I gave it a quick try. My solution passed all the testcases.

Link to the problem: [Problem: (A) Mike and palindrome](https://codeforces.com/contest/798/problem/A)

**Question:**

> Mike has a string s consisting of only lowercase English letters. He wants to change exactly one character from the string so that the resulting one is a palindrome.
>
> A palindrome is a string that reads the same backward as forward, for example strings  "z", "aaa", "aba", "abccba" are palindromes, but strings "codeforces", "reality", "ab" are not.
>
> **Input**
>
> > The first and single line contains string s (1 ≤ |s| ≤ 15).
>
> **Output**
>
> > Print "YES" (without quotes) if Mike can change exactly one character so that the resulting string is palindrome or "NO" (without quotes) otherwise.
>
> **Examples**
>
> **input**: abccaa  **output**: YES
>
> **input**: abbcca  **output**: NO
>
> **input**: abcda   **output**: YES

#### CODE

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    int i{0}, j{str.length() - 1}, cnt{0};
   
   // Check from both the ends if characters are equal.
    while(i < j){
        if (str[i]!= str[j]) ++cnt;
        
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
    
    // If there's one mismatch.
    if ( cnt == 1 ) std::cout << "YES";
    // Odd length string with 0 mismatches e.g: abcba, can change middle char.
    else if ( cnt == 0 && str.length()&1 ) std::cout << "YES";
    else std::cout << "NO";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Formatting: Don't be so stingy with the indentation, give your code some room to breathe!

Validating input: You should check if `std::cin` was successful.

It is always good if you can split out complexities into functions. Your `main` function does it all, read input, calc result, and write the output. I would suggest you created a separate function to determine if the string is a palindrome:

```
bool isPalindromeWithOneChange(const std::string& str) {
    // ...
    // ...
    return cnt == 1 || (cnt == 0 && length % 2);
}
```

And change `main` to the following:

```
int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    if (std::cin.fail() || std::cin.bad()) {
        std::cerr << "Input failure";
        return 1;
    }
    if (isPalindromeWithOneChange(str))
        std::cout << "YES";
    else
        std::cout << "NO";
}
```

Note that the underlying data type for array indexes and length is `size_t`.

This is just personal preferences, but I find the following easier to read with the decleration on seperate lines:

```cpp
const std::size_t length = str.length();
std::size_t i = 0;
std::size_t j = length - 1;
std::size_t cnt = 0;
```

With the decleration of `length` you can replace this line:

```cpp
else if ( cnt == 0 && str.length()&1 ) std::cout << "YES";
```

With the following

```cpp
else if ( cnt == 0 && length % 2) std::cout << "YES";
```

You can break out of the `while` loop as soon as `cnt` is larger than one.

---

Final nitpicking / brain farts

Whether you use `length & 1` or `length % 2` is entirely up to you but one thing you lose with `& 1` is the intention. You should write what you want your code to do and rely on the compiler to handle it correctly.

Comment: Any decent compiler will generate exactly the same code for `& 1` and `% 2` if optimizations are turned on, at least if it can see that `length` is an unsigned number.

Comment: @upkajdt Thank you for the review. `length&1` is a force of habit.

Comment: @upkajdt *Do you know why the formatting does not work correctly in the last paragraph?* Apparently, If you put a newline after `<br>` it should work

Comment: @Ch3steR, thanks, that fixed it. I would suggest you have a look at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ if you like these sorts of challenges.

Comment: BTW: Nearly always, prefer `std::string_view` over `std::string const&` for parameter-type. The exception is if you might need zero-termination, or called code expects that exact type.

Comment: @Deduplicator, you are correct. My head is still stuck in 2016 :-)